# How to run a UI workflow for n times and get result in Jasmine it block and perform assertion

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, webdriver-io, jasmine-node

I have to execute a UI workflow using nodes-selenium webdriver n times and calculate the average timing and assert it in jasmine it block.

I have tried several ways but can't figure out how this can be achieved in Jasmine it() block .

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly it is strange task for e2e tests. I'm sure that you should
  use tools for performance testing instead of trying to do a bicycle
  using webdriver.
- You can get execution time for each `it()` using some custom timer in
  `BeforeEach()` and `AfterEach`. I'm not sure if exists a way to get
  an execution time from jasmine runner directly.